# Pytrends Installation in Jupyter

Tags: python, installation, jupyter

Having an issue installing pytrends for Jupyter

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pytrends


Collecting pytrends
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytrends/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pytrends/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

Since December have you find an answer to your problem? Because I try this one month ago with Jupyter and Google Colab, and it works well.

If you "only" do this command: `!pip install pytrend` does it work for you. OK on my side, indeed.

How do you install Jupyter `Anaconda` or with the `pip install` command?

Will be curious to have your feedback on this one.

Have a nice day, Arthur